# Expression Tree Property Setter InvalidCastException

Tags: c#, lambda, expression

I am defining a collection of mappings in code at design time and then executing those mappings at run time after doing some data extraction :

```
public class FormExtractionMap<T>
{
    public Expression<Func<T>> Destination { get; set; }

    public string Source { get; set; }

}
```

Mapping Code:

```
var extractionRequest = new ExtractionRequest<PlanningApplication>
    {
        Mapping = new List<FormExtractionMap<PlanningApplication>>
        {
            new FormExtractionMap<PlanningApplication> {Destination = x => x.Site.Address.MapCoordinate.Eastings, Source = "site_address_easting"},
            new FormExtractionMap<PlanningApplication> {Destination = x => x.Site.Address.MapCoordinate.Northings, Source = "site_address_northing"},
        }
    };
```

and then I'm looking through each of the mapping expressions to go and get the Source value (any Type) and then assign it to the Destination Expression (any Type).

```
        foreach (var extractionMap in extractionRequest.Mapping)
        {
            extractionRequest.ExtractTo.Set(extractionMap.Destination, form.GetValue(extractionMap.Source));
        }
```

I then have Expression extensions to create a setter, compile and do the property assignment.

```
    public static TEntity Set<TEntity, TProperty>(
        this TEntity obj,
        Expression<Func<TEntity, TProperty>> selector,
        TProperty value)
    {
        var setterExpr = CreateSetter(selector);
        setterExpr.Compile()(obj, value);
        return obj;
    }

    private static Expression<Action<TEntity, TProperty>> CreateSetter<TEntity, TProperty>(Expression<Func<TEntity, TProperty>> selector)
    {
        ParameterExpression valueParameterExpression = Expression.Parameter(typeof(TProperty), "value");
        Expression targetExpression = selector.Body is UnaryExpression ? ((UnaryExpression)selector.Body).Operand : selector.Body;
        var newValue = Expression.Parameter(selector.Body.Type);

        return Expression.Lambda<Action<TEntity, TProperty>>
        (
            Expression.Assign(targetExpression, Expression.Convert(valueParameterExpression, targetExpression.Type)),
            selector.Parameters.Single(),
            valueParameterExpression
        );
    }
```

if Source is a string and the Destination is a string the value is assigned fine. If the Destination is a double on **setterExpr.Compile()(obj, value);** I get :

> System.InvalidCastException : Unable to cast object of type
> 'System.String' to type 'System.Double'.

I thought the "Expression.Convert" was handling the type conversion but clearly not. What am I doing wrong please ?

Comment: It helps if you write the desired expression as comments in your code, to visualize what you are trying to build.

Comment: targetExpression can be any Type,
valueParameterExpression could potentially be any type but only those that can convert to targetExpression.

Is there a way to get the compiler to coerse the value? i.e. "12345" should fit into a double or string?

Comment: Why are you unwrapping the `UnaryExpression` from `selector.Body`? Isn't that leading to your cast exception? Is that because the selector may have a cast to object?

Comment: @JeremyLakeman "selector" is coming through as "{x => Convert(x.Site.Address.MapCoordinate.Eastings, Object)}". After, the targetExpression is set to "{x.Site.Address.MapCoordinate.Eastings}" Expression..Assign seems to work in string to string cases. If I just take selector.Body, I get an System.ArgumentException: 'Expression must be writeable '
 on the return statement

Comment: If you unwrap the Object cast, you'll have to use the underlying type to build your final lambda.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I did eventually solve this. Expression.Convert is akin to an explicit cast (Foo)Bar, not as "Convert" implies. I ended up with:

```
private static Expression<Action<TEntity, TProperty>> CreateSetter<TEntity, TProperty>(
            Expression<Func<TEntity, TProperty>> selector, Type valueParameterType)
        {
            ParameterExpression valueParameterExpression = Expression.Parameter(typeof(object), "value");
            Expression targetExpression = selector.Body is UnaryExpression ? ((UnaryExpression)selector.Body).Operand : selector.Body;
            
            var resultBody = ConvertToDestination(valueParameterExpression, valueParameterType, targetExpression);
            
            return Expression.Lambda<Action<TEntity, TProperty>>
            (
                Expression.Assign(targetExpression, resultBody),
                selector.Parameters.Single(),
                valueParameterExpression
            );

        }

        private static Expression ConvertToDestination(ParameterExpression valueParameterExpression, Type valueParameterType, Expression targetExpression)
        {
            if (valueParameterType == typeof(string))
            {
                switch (targetExpression.Type)
                {
                    case Type _ when targetExpression.Type == typeof(double):
                        return Expression.Call(typeof(Convert), "ToDouble", null, valueParameterExpression);

                    case Type _ when targetExpression.Type == typeof(int):
                        return Expression.Call(typeof(Convert), "ToInt", null, valueParameterExpression);

                    default:
                        return Expression.Convert(valueParameterExpression, targetExpression.Type);
                }
            }

            return Expression.Convert(valueParameterExpression, targetExpression.Type);
        }
```

However, I thought it was messy, verbose and frankly unnecessary as I was able to implement similar functionality using AutoMapper in a few hours. Automapper does a better job of type conversion, caching the maps etc. So the real solution was re-factor and don't re-invent the wheel.